# On edit trigger for send email function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to create a script and/or trigger that will send an email to a small group of users anytime a value is entered into cells within a specific column of a google sheet. I am able to get the send email function to work properly but all the triggers I have attached the current script that is functional as far as sending the email, I just need a way to trigger it via script or the actual triggers wizard.

I tried an on edit trigger but I do not think I was using it correctly OR it doesn't have the permissions needed to send an email.

```
 function myFunction() {// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EmailScript").getRange("B2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'L&F cash amount entered!'; // Second column
var subject = 'L&F Cash';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

I want for an email to be sent anytime a value is entered into any cell within column D.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. What kind of triggers do you tried, simple or installable? Do you already look at the execution transcript or executions/executions errors for your project on https://script.google.com?

Comment: onEdit() trigger is probably what you want.  Just use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers)